# Why does display:flex cause divs to not line-break

Tags: html, css

See my CodePen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/QwMWyM

Why is the test on the right-hand side of the SVG image? Actually it should line-break, should it not?

I want to vertically center both within a div. What is wrong with my approach?

```
<div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/linking/link01.svg" alt="svgme" />
        </div>
        <div class="commandName">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is what flex was invented for, but you can use `flex-direction:column` to arrange the items in a column istead of a row.

Comment: Nice thanks that worked. Seems I have really dig into flexbox layout doing an app were we only support IE9 half-hearted :P